# Load/import settings from one project to another?

Tags: customization, startup-file

I have created a new startup file in order to improve my workflow.  One example among many others, I've created new Screens Layouts. It really makes a difference. But when I open old saved files, they use old settings like old Screen Layouts. It's time consuming to re-adjust the settings one by one to my new liking. It's also the same problem if I open blend files created by other people, I'm forced to use their settings.

So, is there a way to override the settings of old files with the ones from my new startup file?

Comment: Fantastic. I thought no one else asked this question, I wasn't looking for the right keywords. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When opening a file uncheck the **Load UI** option.

[image]

Comment: then, save the file, so that its new ui becomes your current and next time you don't need to deactivate that option.